# Changing routing location from a function

Tags: angularjs, function, location

So I want to change the routing location in AngularJS using $location.path within a function, but It doesn't work.

```
app.controller('globalCtrl', function($scope, $route, $location){
 $scope.changePath = function(newPath){
     $location.path(newPath);
 };

 $scope.changePath("/login");
}
```

How should I call the function or what should I do?

Comment: why check `location`? Is it for checking current route?

Comment: I don't want to check it, I want to change It

Comment: so use `$location.path(newPath)`

Comment: It's the same thing, this is not the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('globalCtrl', ['$scope','location', function($scope, $location){
 $scope.changePath = function(newPath){
     $location.path(newPath);
 };

 $scope.changePath("/login");
}]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, so in AngularJS 1 you can't change the $location in a function, so the only way is, I think , by using, after changing the $location , an $interval :

```
 $interval(function(). {$location.hash($location.hash())},200);
```

So this function will reactualize the location every 2ms.